# Extra branch displayed in Xcode Source Control Pane

Tags: xcode, git

Weird issue here.  I merged two branches with different feature sets.  I branched from one of the two then merged in the second (using command line).  Now in Xcode's source control pane it shows two different branches as current. It's not a big deal but I would like to know how to get rid of the top one (at the very least) and preferably to understand why both would be displayed as current. It makes pushing to remotes a bit of a headache because they have the same app name and so I need to make sure I don't push to the wrong branch.  I don't particularly want to have to redo things a different way since the branches had a fair number of merge conflicts.

[image: Screenshot of extra branch in Xcode Source Control Pane]

Comment: Even after I cloned a new version of the remote and still have the extra branch there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... There were two files that were pointing to the other branch folders in the pbxproj file.  This appears to have happened when I merged.  Removing the references to these files and pointing to the files in the correct project folder then committing and pushing made the extra branches go away.